Compare means for discrete data
I have two sets of observations which correspond to the number of words in dactylic hexameters in two different Greek authors. The histogram has a nice bell shape, but the data is not normal: there can only be discrete number of words in a verse. It is not Poisson, either: variance is smaller than the mean (empirically, a verse has no less 4 words and no more than 12).

What are the ways to compare two means to say if they are significantly different?
I was thinking of chi-square for comparison of 2 distributions, but this way, it seems that we are treating 5-word lines and, say, 6-word lines as categorical data (which is not totally devoid of sense, but awkward).
Another option would be to compute means for every n lines (say, 5), and then apply a z-test or a t-test (by Central Limit Theorem).
Both solutions, however, seem far-fetched. Is there a more elegant solution?
upd. Following the suggestions from comments below, I add the results of the Shapiro tests and a qq-plot.
a) Shapiro-Wilk normality test for the Agronautica sample returns
W = 0.94682, p-value = 2.056e-12; for the Iliad sample -- W = 0.95116, p-value = 8.582e-12
b) QQ-plots look similar for both samples:

upd2: adding the tables of counts for each sample (first line is the number of words in a verse)
iliad_sample
4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
13  33 115 128 124  69  13   3   2
argo_sample
4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11
22  67 136 149  85  32   7   2

Welcome to Cross Validated! $//$ $1)$ Another option would be to compute means for every n lines (say, 5), and then apply a z-test or a t-test (by Central Limit Theorem). What does this do for you? $//$ $2)$ What issues do you see about using the methods you have learned for normal data, such as a t-test of two groups? (I know what issues I see, and your response to my question will be informative.)


Since samples means are normally distributed, we can apply tests for normal data. So I assumed it could be a way to avoid dealing with discrete data.
A t-test assumes that data is normally distributed, which is not true in my case, since the distribution of words in a verse is not continuous.


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You appear to misunderstand the central limit theorem and how it might come into this. The properties of a two sample t-test should be fine for comparing samples of this size from effectively bounded variables that won't be very skewed. The bigger issue is that there's no clear sense in which you appear to be randomly sampling from a population of interest. What are the populations of interest and what is your actual null hypotheses and alternative hypothesis (which would be a statement about some population parameter, or perhaps a statement about a function involving several of them)

... Note, by the way, that if your populations are identical to your samples, there's nothing to infer.

@Glen_b My populations of interest are all the hexameter lines from Homer and Apollonius. The null hypothesis is that there is no significant difference of means. The alternative hypothesis is that one of the authors tends to use longer words (hence the number of words in a line would be smaller). I take it as peculiar feature of an author’s style. What is available is, say, 15-30 000 lines from each poem. With modern computer tools, I can calculate the mean for all of them. But a) this is not the whole population anyway — we cannot have all the lines written by any poet whatsoever.

b) If I calculate the means and standard deviations for the whole poems, how do I say if it is statistically significant? The problem remains.

@LocusClassicus Relative to your point (b): if the poems you have were the whole population of interest, you wouldn't need tests at all. Tests are meant to infer something about the population, from a sample taken from this population. If you have data for the whole population and observe different means in your two groups of interest, you don't need a test to say the means are different, they just are. Judging if the observed difference is important or not (practical significance) is something different from statistical significance.

@J-J-J That is a fare point, and something I have been thinking about a lot in connection with various literary measures. If two (or more) authors are compared, our populations are all they have written, which is in practice never attainable. What we have is always some sort of selection (a natural sample, if you wish) from the general oevre. If so,  we need to do some testing, needn't we?

Could you give the distributions as tables of counts?

@NickCox yes, added to the original post

Would you consider treating it as an ordered categorical variables and doing ordinal regression? That would not get you a mean but would confirm that one author used more words per hexameter.

@mdewey That seems a trifle timid.  Number of words would seem to be ratio scale, although we don't have to exploit that.

@LocusClassicus In that case, the actual intent, presumably, would be to treat the available works as a random sample of the works they could have produced. More specifically, to treat each author's currently known work as the output of a process and then to make inferences not about the known works but about the process that produced them (i.e. about characteristics of the authors rather than the specific available works). The data are then not the populations of interest. There's several issues with this; an authors output is neither independent nor identically distributed for one thing.

This is a very good point, thanks! You are right that the very notion of population needs to be more clearly defined.

My take on this is different. Posing this as a question about means, or about medians, or about any other summary, is an example of what Whitehead called misplaced concreteness. The question of interest to me is more diffuse, at least in the first instance: How do the distributions compare?
Incidentally, the OP's edit shows that we have samples of 500 hexameters. So, populations are clearly definable, the complete works being sampled. Whether there is a wider population behind and beyond, e.g. as defining the style of particular authors or groups of authors, I happily leave open.
Like the OP, I want it both ways.

The variables are discrete and necessarily positive. So, neither variable can be taken completely seriously as candidates for being normal or Gaussian. But neither are many examples often presented as good fits to normal distributions, such as people's heights, necessarily positive, continuous in principle, but conventionally measured in cm or inches.

At least for descriptive or exploratory graphical purposes, a normal quantile plot (normal probability plot, normal scores plot, probit plot, fractile diagram) is a good conventional starting point. The normal distribution is a reference case in the same way that circular shapes or sea level are reference cases for shapes that we don't expect all or even ever to be exactly circular, or landsurface altitudes that we don't expect all or even ever to be at sea level.


The large number of ties is clear but showing them graphically is not especially helpful.
I used what in my reading are most often called ridits, which are for each distinct value, number of words $4(1)12$,
$$ (\text{fraction} \lt \text{value})\ + \ (1/2)\ (\text{fraction} = \text{value}),$$
OR
$$ (\text{fraction} \le \text{value})\ - \ (1/2)\ (\text{fraction} = \text{value}),$$
but I show them on a normal quantile scale. (Apologies to those who would prefer that I introduce notation or use more formal language.)
Ridits have many other names, such as average cumulative proportions;
the mid-distribution function; the grade function; cumulative proportions to midpoint. (The last term appeared in a much used textbook by Dixon and Massey, some years before Bross introduced and named ridits, and the idea is likely to be even older. Bross admitted late in life that he was just choosing a punchy term like logit or probit or rankit, but honouring his wife Rida.)
The merit of this plot could only be that it helps anyone to see coarse and fine structure comparing the distributions. Use of the normal as a reference is less important than that it gives us a way to compare the distributions with each other. Although your view may be different, I think it is sufficiently clearer than a histogram to be worth looking at. I see a systematic shift, typically use of more words in the Iliad, and hints of extra structure that should be interpreted with extreme caution.
A formal test of normality such as Shapiro-Wilk seems to me fairly pointless.

I used Stata, but coding is, or should be, trivial in your favourite software if different. It may help that I started with this version of the data.
clear
input float(n_words iliad argo)
 4  13  22
 5  33  67
 6 115 136
 7 128 149
 8 124  85
 9  69  32
10  13   7
11   3   2
12   2   0
end

So the cumulative probabilities to midpoint for the Iliad run from 6.5/500 to 499/500 and the corresponding standard normal deviates to 7 d.p. run from $-$2.2262118 to 2.8781617.

Wow, this is a kind of theoretical solution I was looking for, thank you. I have profited from reading Bross’s article “How to use Ridit Analysis”, but some practical details are not yet clear.
Bross says that the mechanics of analysis “can be learned in 10 minutes”, and indeed I have been able to quickly compute the ridits for both groups (separately), but I still cannot quite see how you arrive at the plot above. There is something going on with the x scale.
So far, my plot looks like this: https://github.com/locusclassicus/stylometry_2024/blob/main/images/redits.png

RIdits are as defined in my answer. Otherwise I am plotting in terms of standard normal deviates but labelling in terms of probabilities. It's just the plot in your question, but with axes swapped, and both distributions.  I've never found the original Bross paper easy to follow.

I added a little detail at the end of my answer.

I think I finally reproduced your plot (in R), and here is the link in case someone is interested).
P.S. Special thanks for the quote from Whitehead. And for a very Platonic point about the ideal nature of continuous distributions. An intellectual feast.

Let me start by clearing up a misconception: you can run all the t-tests you want on discrete data. Continuous is not a required asssumption (e.g. the $Chi^2$ test is used to compare binomial data...)
Your situation with "failing" normality tests is quite common, and nothing to worry about. It is not due to the discrete nature of the data, but to the ties in the data (many values are equal). This occurs frequently e.g. in industrial settings, with continuous data, where the resolution of your measurement system is coarse: so you get many data points with the same value. Normality tests systematically fail when you have many ties (because, in a sample from a TRUE normal population, there would be virtually no ties).
In you particular case, with unimodal, symmetrical-ish distribution, the t-test is perfectly valid. I would use a Welch t-test, as your Iliad distribution seems to have a larger variance.
Now a Welch t-test (if significant) will tell you that on average, one source uses more words. That may (or not?) be what you wanted to prove.
You could also, as suggested, run a Mann-Whitney U test. But the M-W U does not test the same thing as a t test. M-W U (if significant) will demonstrate that one group (most likely Iliad in your case) is stochastically greater than the other (ie. the number of words used is most often larger than in the other group: i.e. $P(words A> words B)>.5$, or if you take a random hexameter from A, and compare it to random hexameter in B, more often than not, A uses more words). That may be as good? But do NOT use M-W U as a test of medians, because this is a narrower perspective, which drags additional assumptions (basically symmetrical distributions, or exactly the same exact distribution, just shifted, which in your case are not met. And when these additional assumptions are violated, M-W U is very non-robust).
And yes, you could also compare proportions (ridits? I thougt ridits were for ordinal data?). What proportion of the hexamers use, say, more than 6 words? For this, you are comparing binomial counts, so a 2x2 contingency table is the right tool. I would use a Fisher exact test, but as long as the counts in all the cells are not too small (some say >5, I tend to use >10: your sample size is large enough that this should be the case most of the time), then $Chi^2$ (normal approximation of the binomial) will give you almost the same results. And then you can do that for any number of words (4-12). And that may be interesting too? Now, if you indeed run multiple Fisher-exact tests, you will face the question of type 1 error inflation due to multiple comparisons which you can handle with the classic Bonferroni or Sidak corrections.

This is most useful indeed, thank you so much! All noted. And yes, both Welch and M-W are significant.

In this case, I would just suggest using the Wilcoxon Rank-Sum Test (also called Mann-Whitney U-Test for some reason) as a non-parametric option since we don't have continuous data and can't really say if the data is normally distributed as you already pointed out.

(1) The Wilcoxon test doesn't answer the question because it doesn't compare means.  What is the problem with a t test or z test?  Both would work very well. (2) Neither the discreteness nor the departure from normality are important determinants of the choice of a test.

@whuber The null hypothesis of the Wilcoxon test is usually taken as equal medians. In a situation where a t test cannot be used, a comparison of medians (instead of comp. of means) is a viable alternative, isn't it? However, my thought was that a parametric test, if possible (is it?), would be preferable.

@whuber I am not sure I understand what you mean by Neither the discreteness nor the departure from normality are important determinants of the choice of a test. T-test does get used on discrete data sometimes, but on what conditions are we justified to do that?

@Locus You have to establish that the sampling distribution of the mean is approximately Normal, that the sampling distribution of the variance is approximately chi-squared, and that the two sampling distributions are approximately independent.  The t-test is used on discrete data a lot.  The classic application is with distributions that look just like these two: namely, Binomial without much skew.

I have added the results of the Shapiro test and a QQ-plot in the original post which confirm that data are not normal... maybe I should be testing for Binomial?

The Normality of the data is scarcely relevant: "sampling distribution of the mean," for instance, is a very different thing.  That's why Normality tests are generally worse than useless (because they don't answer the relevant question and, being formal tests, are inferior to suitable graphical explorations of the distributions).  In this case non-Normality is a foregone conclusion due to the many ties in the data: that is, its discreteness, which brings us back full circle to my original comment.

Assuming you have tested both the groups separately for normality and that at least one of them indicates non-normality, you can compare the medians of words in dactylic hexameters of the two authors using Mann-Whitney U-test.
PS. with large enough data, you can use a t-test when your outcome variable is discrete due to the test's robustness. The test is a popular one for this particular reason. Of course, you must ensure that none of the assumptions of the test is violated before proceeding.

Thanks, it is good to know that t-test can be used with discrete data. However, how do I ensure that non of the assumptions is violated? Shapiro test says my data are not normal (naturally), and q-q plot looks like a ladder (:

Normality of data in both the groups is an assumption,  which has been violated, so you may skip checking the rest. I'd also suggest you edit the question to add the QQ plot and the result of SW test (would be good, generally speaking)

done, thank you for the suggestion @peacer

Mann-Whitney U does not test equality of medians... It does so only under some additional assumptions, which are basically untestable, and which here seem violated, in which cases you can not interpret a significant result.

@jginestet thanks for your answer above and this comment. Looks like there's a lot to unlearn and relearn! Seems like academic teaching, unfortunately, needs improvement. Wish I knew this before about MWU test. Once again, grateful for your contribution

Interesting read
